# Dynamic binding: Getting the field dynamically

Tags: c#

I've been writing a generic method that converts an IEnumerable to a data table:

```
public static DataTable DataCast (Type t) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dynamic Data = DataBase.GetTable(t); // this is Linq to SQL DataContext.GetTable();
    var Fields = t.GetFields();
    foreach (var i in Data) {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int y = 0; y < Fields.Length; y++) {
            String F = Fields[y].Name.Split('.').Last();
            // Stuck at this part dt.Columns.Add(i.F);                                     
        }
    }  
    return dt;
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to get the fields of `i` according to the value of `F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FieldInfo.GetValue(instance)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead:

```
for (int y = 0; y < Fields.Length; y++) {
    dt.Columns.Add(Fields[y].GetValue(i));
}
```

Comment: I must have lost my mind, I knew about that method. :p